# How to copy the PowerPivot data into the Excel workbook as a table with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

I have found in another post how to copy PowerPivot data into an Excel 2013 workbook, [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510224/how-do-you-copy-the-powerpivot-data-into-the-excel-workbook-as-a-table). But now I want to do the same thing as the answer but with a macro. (Unfortunately I can't leave a comment so I have to ask it as a new question.)

What I want to do is done by the following steps:

1. Select the **Data tab**
2. Select **Existing connections**
3. Choose the connection one wants.
4. Press **Ok**
5. Press **Table** at the radio button option
6. Choose a new sheet (you can choose to put it somewhere in an existing as well but not what i try to do here.)
7. Press **Ok**

I can't record a macro while I do this, so do anyone know the VBA code to do this?

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: excel 2013... (do it matter?)

Comment: Yes - those steps don't work in 2010. :)

Comment: Ok, good to know :) but you don't know the answer to the question?

Comment: I don't have 2013 available here to test. If you do it manually, then in the immediate window enter: `?activesheet.listobjects(1).querytable.connection`, what output do you get?

Comment: Sry but I don't understand which "immediate window" I should enter it...

Comment: Open the VB editor, press Ctrl+G (or View - Immediate Window) and paste the code in, then press Enter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75930/discussion-between-erik-dahlen-and-rory).

Comment: that same link you provided gives an option to do the same thing using PowerQuery, which is available as a free add-in to Excel 2010.

Comment: yes, I saw that, but is it easier do write a macro for PowerQuery to fetch data than for PowerPivot? And do you know how to do this?